terminated with error org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ResultStage
While executing the spark application in yarn i was facing the following issue twice or thrice a day these days.
ERROR MicroBatchExecution:91 - Query [id = 0ec965b7-5dda-43be-940c-3ec8672bcd5c, runId = 17c15719-ab20-4488-ba37-ccf6a6ca27e1] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ResultStage 185575 (start at DeviceLocationDataListener.scala:148) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Stream is corrupted
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:554)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:470)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:64)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409) at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(generated.java:184)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(generated.java:206)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409) at scala.collection.Iterator$class.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:331)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1334) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.nonEmpty(TraversableOnce.scala:111)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.nonEmpty(Iterator.scala:1334) at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$$anonfun$save$1.apply(MongoSpark.scala:117)
at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$$anonfun$save$1.apply(MongoSpark.scala:117) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.refill(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:202)
at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.read(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:157) at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.read(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:170)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply$mcJ$sp(Utils.scala:361) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply(Utils.scala:348)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply(Utils.scala:348) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyStream(Utils.scala:369)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:462) ... 32 more
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
I suppose, it was casused when executing the following code:
df.writeStream
  .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
    batchDF.persist()
    
------mongo insert 1---------
------mongo insert 2---------

batchDF
  .select(DeviceIOIDS.TENANTGROUPUID.value, DeviceIOIDS.WORKERID.value, DeviceIOIDS.TASKUID.value)
  .groupBy(DeviceIOIDS.TENANTGROUPUID.value, DeviceIOIDS.WORKERID.value, DeviceIOIDS.TASKUID.value)
  .count()
  .withColumnRenamed("count", "recordcount")
  .withColumn(DeviceIOIDS.ISTRANSFERRED.value, lit(0))
  .withColumn(DeviceIOIDS.INSERTDATETIME.value, current_timestamp())
  .withColumn(DeviceIOIDS.INSERTDATE.value, current_date())
  .write
  .mode("Append")
  .mongo(
    WriteConfig(
      "mongo.dbname".getConfigValue,
      "mongo.devicelocationtransferredstatus".getConfigValue
    )
  )

batchDF.unpersist()
}

Thanks for the help
